# Почему мог разлогиниться из StackOverflow?

Tags: поддержка, аутентификация

Час назад заходил на SO. Сейчас зашёл - разлогинен. Историю не стирал, с других устройств не заходил, пароль не менял. В чем может быть причина? Нужно ли бить тревогу и пароли менять?

Использую логин через StackExchange, привязан аккаунт Google и Facebook.

Firefox 42, uBlock Origin 1.3.2., но на сайтах SO он отключен.

Comment: Периодически такое тоже происходит.

Comment: Проверьте, не угнали ли у вас гугл с фейсбуком. :)

Comment: @Discord нет, там левых логинов не было, сразу проверил. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Если ip динамический, то может быть разлогин.
2. Если прокси, то тоже. У меня часто на SO слетает авторизация, когда я по VPN из Сингапура хожу.
3. Банально истекло время сессии.

Comment: Точно, с работы может быть динамический ip.